# CentOS6 --skip-broken

Tags: centos6

my linux skills are not so good and i cant fix my problem..

Im trying to update (yum update) my 2 linux virtual machines. i get allways following error:

```
Error: Package: nss-3.28.4-3.el6_9.x86_64 (updates)
Requires: nspr >= 4.13.0
Installed: nspr-4.11.0-1.el6.x86_64 (@base)
nspr = 4.11.0-1.el6
Error: Package: nss-util-3.28.4-1.el6_9.x86_64 (updates)
Requires: nspr >= 4.13.0-1
Installed: nspr-4.11.0-1.el6.x86_64 (@base)
nspr = 4.11.0-1.el6
You can try to use --skip-broken to get around the problem.
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

(Note: the text above is a translation from German; it may not be the exact same text as you'd get if you run the commands on a system with English locale.)

How do I fix this?

Comment: change your locale if you like to post errors. Not everybody is able to read german. Use **LANG=C command options** in future.

Answer (score 1):

your packet database seems to be inconsistent

try:

```
  yum clean all
  yum repolist
  yum upgrade
```

UPDATE:
copy the baseurl line to sections you need.

```
[base] name=Mnet-CentOS-$releasever - Base 
#mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releaseve‌​r&arch=$basearch&rep‌​o=os 
baseurl=http://centos.bio.lmu.de/$releasever/os/$basearch/ gpgcheck=1 
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6 #released updates 

[updates] name=Mnet-CentOS-$releasever - Updates 
#mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releaseve‌​r&arch=$basearch&rep‌​o=updates 
baseurl=http://centos.bio.lmu.de/$releasever/os/$basearch/ gpgcheck=1 
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
```

Comment: i did it already, but it does't solve my problem

Comment: look at output of **LANG=C yum info nspr** ! If you don't get **Version: 4.13.1** in **Available Packages** your database is outdated. And I am sure you will not get. Check your mirror.

Comment: i've got 4.11.0 / Release 1.e16

Comment: #released updates
[updates]
name=CentOS-6 - Updates
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=6&arch=$basearch&repo=updates
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/updates/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6

Comment: try with this german mirror `baseurl=http://centos.bio.lmu.de/$releasever/os/$basearch/` in CentOS-Base.repo - I am syncing from this source to my own repo

Comment: could you post your whole repository please.

Comment: I updated answer with repository example

Answer (score 0):

Check what repositories you have enabled, try disabling them one by one - this can happen when two different versions of the same package (or a package with the same name) are offered by two different repositories.

Take a look here for more info: https://www.unixmen.com/enable-disable-repositories-centos/